# What percentage of nodes currently support segwit?

Tags: segregated-witness, nodes, statistics

What percentage of nodes currently support segwit?

It seems [Bitnodes](https://bitnodes.earn.com/nodes/) could figure this out, but I can't find such a stat on its website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Luke-Jr's statistics](https://luke.dashjr.org/programs/bitcoin/files/charts/services.html), 96.15% of nodes are advertising the Segwit P2P protocol service bit, which implies that they support segwit.